# How to align an image and text

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I am coding a Facebook clone with some changes to enhance my skills, but I have ran into a problem.

I have an image(profile picture) and text(user name) under the `<h1>` of Home. I am trying to align the text exactly to the center to the right of the image
example:

```
[
top of image
CENTER OF IMAGE  TEXT
bottom of image
] ( what I expected/Wanted)
```

I am not getting the result I want. Instead, the image the text is at the top to the right of the image.
example:

```
[
top of image
center of image
BOTTOM OF IMAGE TEXT
](result)
```

The HTML:

```
        <div class="sidebar">
            <h1 class="home">Home</h1> 
            <a class="create-button" href="#">Create</a>

            <div class="personnal-info">
                <img class="sidebar-profile-picture" src="icons\my profile.jpg">
                <p class="my-user-name">Said User</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 55px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

.home {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px; 
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}

.create-button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: rgb(23, 93, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 220px;
}

.sidebar-profile-picture {
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.my-user-name {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: text-align: end; ?

Comment: I do not know if you intend it to be in  the my-user-name. I tried it but it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try float:left; on the img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is perfect for these cases. Change the `.personalInfo` div to a flexbox by adding the `display: flex` property. Then you have access to many other properties for centering, etc.

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 55px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }

.home {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 35px; 
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
}

.create-button {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: rgb(23, 93, 255);
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 220px;
}

.sidebar-profile-picture {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px; /* demo only */
    background-color: blue; /* demo only */
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.my-user-name {
    /* display: inline-block; -> not necessary anymore*/ 
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-family: Roboto, Arial;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* FLEXBOX */
.personal-info{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* display children in a horizontal row */
  align-items: center; /* vertically align items in the center */
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
    <h1 class="home">Home</h1> 
    <a class="create-button" href="#">Create</a>

    <div class="personal-info">
        <img class="sidebar-profile-picture">
        <p class="my-user-name">Said User</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your requirement correctly.
You can use flex to achieve the below result.
Let me know if this works

```css
.personnal-info {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center
}
```

```html
 <div class="sidebar">
            <h1 class="home">Home</h1> 
            <a class="create-button" href="#">Create</a>

            <div class="personnal-info">
                <img class="sidebar-profile-picture" src="//via.placeholder.com/50x50">
                <p class="my-user-name">Said User</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I rounded the picture so  it was not exactly at the middle of the picture. But it was really near it so it did accomplish what I wanted to. Thanks !

Comment: 0


hey Mihai T thanks for the response ! It actually worked. But didn't put it in an ideal position. I actually fixed the problem by putting position: relative; on personnal-info. Then I put in my-user-name position: absolute; top: -8px; PS: It also worked with bottom: -8px; instead of top: -8px. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

hey  Mihai T thanks for the response ! It actually worked.
But didn't put it in an ideal position.
I actually fixed the problem by putting `position: relative;` on personnal-info.
Then I put in my-user-name
`position: absolute; top: -8px;`
PS: It also worked with `bottom: -8px;` instead of `top: -8px`.
Thanks !

Comment: Please add this as a comment to my answer. Not as an actual answer :) and also rate my answer as accepted if it worked. Thank you !